# QuantumFramework: Error message when calculating a CircuitOperator

Tags: quantum-computing

I am running the following package and code:

```
PacletInstall[ResourceObject["https://wolfr.am/11ftY6W2s"]]
<< Wolfram`QuantumFramework`
testcircuit = QuantumCircuitOperator[{QuantumOperator[{"H", 2}]}]
testcircuit["CircuitOperator"]
```

Why do I get the following error code after running the last line?
[image]

I have no clue why this occurs. The operator is expected to be 4 * 4-dimensional. Variations of the code with other circuits did not avoid such an error message. I tried to create a minimal example. My goal is to extract the operator of the whole circuit as a 4 * 4 matrix.

Comment: Have you tried crossposting this on Wolfram Community?

Comment: This works for me using Paclet version 1.0.17, installed via PacletInstall["https://wolfr.am/DevWQCF", ForceVersionInstall -> True]. No errors from CircuitOperator, and I can use the output with subsequent commands. One of (the?) developer of the paclet posted on Wolfram Community 1-2 months ago, and I copied this command from his post. Three differences: no ResourceObject, a different URL, and the ForceVersionInstall option. There is also an official Wolfram paclet repository, with an older version of the paclet, but the developer posts updated , but possibly unofficial versions at this URL.

Comment: If you wish to use the paclet from the Wolfram repository instead, the appropriate command is:PacletInstall[ResourceObject["Wolfram/QuantumFramework"]]. Update using ResourceUpdate["Wolfram/QuantumFramework"].